# Magento 1.9.3.1 - Error 500 on products in cart if updated in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, error, http-error-500

I'm running Magento 1.9.3.1 and I'm having a very weird issue I never encountered having multiple Magento websites.

If I add a product to cart then update it in back office, I have an error 500 on frontend on all pages. I have to delete browser history to get the pages back.

Any idea on what could be causing this ? Could it be a Magento bug ?

Logs are giving :

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Item/Option/Collection.php on line 101 **on home page**
>
> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2245 bytes) in app/code/local/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php on line 1138 **on category page**
>
> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 98 bytes) in lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291 **on product page**
>
> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 256 bytes) in lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php on line 195 **on cart page**

I'm on a dedicated server running multiple Magento stores OK.

Comment: try this once : https://techjam.gr/2012/magento/solve-magento-500-internal-server-errors/

Comment: I get the same errors as display in my thread

Comment: means not in log, check what error you are seeing in frontend pages....

Comment: Sometimes I get the same type of error as in logs like Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 112 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php on line 195 (category page), sometimes I just get a blank page.

Comment: from when you are facing these errors , did you recently installed any extensions or did you done any file changes ?

Comment: Well I could not say, as the only way to reproduce this is to add a product in cart and update it in back office while it is in my cart. I recently updated from 19.3.0 (version installed for dev, the website has been in production for less than a week) to 1.9.3.1 using ftp upload. I'm using J2T design Reward Points, it's the only thing I installed besides the theme extensions (I only use a slideshow).

Comment: I tried the mangento cleanup tool, no luck.

Comment: I tried the magento check tool, everything is fine.

Comment: I also tried to remove htaccess, same problem.

Comment: firstly try disabling `J2T design Reward Points` extension in `app/etc/` folder, after that try switching to default theme.....

Comment: Same problem, this is really weird.

Comment: if there is any other modules left , than try disable all, if stilll didt work, thn try contacting hosting team once....

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, problem seems to come from j2t design Reward points extensions, I tried to disable it again, and page loads fine. I will contact them. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be chances that If you are using any 3rd Party extensions you will face these kind of errors , disable those extensions in app/etc/modules folder & try....

Comment: That did the job indeed, my problem here is J2T Design reward points